# How to limit max file size for upload in nginx for special location with fastcgi

Tags: nginx

I want to limit max file size for upload to server to 501kb for location /account/personal_info/documents/ and 50k for other URL of my site for security (ddos, etc)
I made config like text below, but second max_body_size in location /account/personal_info/documents/ does not work at all.
How should I do that?

```
 location / {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/www/mysite.sock;
    client_max_body_size 50k;
 }

 location /account/personal_info/documents/ {
    client_max_body_size 501k;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/www/mysite.sock;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO /account/personal_info/documents/;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the URI really and exactly `http(s)://example.com/account/personal_info/documents/` in your browser? If so, be more specific in your configuration to make sure nginx applies the correct location block.

```
location = /account/personal_info/documents/ {
    # ...
}
```